# Expandable Tool selection button similar to Expression Blend/Photoshop

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking for a control like the one in Expression Blend and Photoshop, which shows a small triangle and when clicked expands an area with more controls.

I could style/program it myself but perhaps there's an already available control out there.

Any help appreciated !!

See picture:

[image: Expandable button example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a `ComboBox`... with `Style`.